# How to insert data into multiple table using python and mysql as fast as possible?

Tags: python, mysql, python-multiprocessing, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I created multiple tables, and I would like to insert data into them as fast as possible.

The code is working right now, but its very slow.

I can only insert 10k data into 10k different table in about 15 secs.
I cannot use `executemany()` because, as far as I understand it, it could only be used if wanted to insert data into the same table, but in my case, I want to insert new data into different table almost every time.

I tried to use pool connection to connect, but it doesn't seem to have so much impact in the speed of the code.

How can I do to make this code faster?

```
import random
import sys
from timeit import default_timer as timer
#from numba import jit, cuda
import string
from mysql.connector import connect, Error, pooling
import os
import multiprocessing


def create_data(data_list, data_loop_ii, step_number):
    current_data = ([data_loop_ii, step_number])
    data_list.append(current_data)

    step_number += 1
    return step_number, data_list


def cpu_func():
    max_space_number = 2 ** 256
    number_of_data_per_side = 10000
    number_of_spaces = 1000000

    step_number = 0

    try:
        connection = connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="admin",
            password="password",
            database="db",
        )
        print("connected to db")

        cursor = connection.cursor()

    except Error as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit()

    number_of_data_per_side_halved = int(number_of_data_per_side/2)

    for space_ii in range(number_of_spaces):
        random_space = random.randrange(0, max_space_number)

        # populate data list
        data_list = []
        for data_loop_ii in range(number_of_data_per_side):
            step_number, data_list = create_data(data_list, data_loop_ii, step_number)

        # populate query list
        insert_query = []
        for current_data in data_list:
            insert_query.append(f"INSERT INTO {current_data[0]} (r_short,r,seed) VALUES ({int(current_data[1])},{str(current_data[2])},{str(current_data[3])})")
            #insert_query += f"INSERT INTO {current_data[0]} (r_short,r,seed) VALUES ({int(current_data[1])},{str(current_data[2])},{str(current_data[3])});"

        # insert query loop
        for current_query in insert_query:
            #print(f"current_query {current_query}")

            try:
                cursor.execute(current_query)
            except:
                print("insert query error")
                sys.exit()

        # commit after query loop is finished
        try:
            connection.commit()
            #connection.close()
        except:
            print("Failure..")
            sys.exit()


cpu_func()
```

(From Comments)

```
CREATE TABLE t_name (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    int_short INT,
    int_long VARCHAR(80))

INSERT INTO t_name (int_short, int_long)
    VALUES
    ( 10982344, 1098234407980983709870987123770928137409128347)
```

(further revisions)

```
CREATE TABLE r (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    r_short int DEFAULT NULL, 
    r varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL, 
    trx_id varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    KEY r_short (r_short), 
    KEY r_short_index (r_short) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1651988598
        DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: By default, MySQL has auto commit enabled. That is almost certainly slowing you down

Comment: *10k different table* o_O seriously? 10k separate tables? similar tables? If so this is very bad structure... and a great opportunity for optimization.

Comment: @DarkKnight The Python DB-API spec requires that auto-commit is off by default on connections, so that probably isn't the issue here (though commit frequency might need tuning, and they should think about parallellising).

Comment: @Akina used more than 10k database because if I use only one it would be more than 1 to
my idea is to make mini database so every database size wont be to large.

Comment: @Akina for exemple if the data i want to insert start with 'a1cb' I insert it in the 'a1cb' database.

Comment: @Akina all the tables all share the same data structure

Comment: @snakecharmerb this is mabe why they tell to use connection.commit() at the end of the queries in the python mysql documentation.
Im total newbie in mysql by the way.

Comment: A bunch of separate small tables is in most cases slower than one combined table with proper indexing.

Comment: @user3639702 up to a point: committing huge amounts of data in a single commit may overwhelm the database server, so it can be necessary to commit in batches.

Comment: @Akina the problem is that my final db will have more than 100 000 000 rows when complete. I tried with a big database, when I want to select all the lines that values=something, it woulb be very slow. even if i use btree index. And I want to make this kind of request thousands of time every minutes. so my idea was make many db to go faster with my request.

Comment: *my final db will have more than 100 000 000 rows when complete* Proper partitioning should solve.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I agree with you. I tried to make a list of all the queries i wanted to perform. then used cursor.execute(queries_list). I also tried with  cursor.execute(queries_list, multi=True), and  cursor.executemany(queries_list).
But they all fail when I want to commit using connection.commit()

Comment: @Akina sorry, its actually 1 000 000 000 rows in total for the full db. I dont know about partitioning, do you think it would work for this kind of database?

Comment: MySQL implements the partitioning. One table is stored in many files, divided by some expression. And while quering the server can detect what partition(s) must be used, and access these partitions only (partition pruning). See [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual / Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html) for details.

Comment: @Akina I cant find any partitioning in the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=34&p=1&q=partition

Comment: I tried to make a big string with all the commands appended together and separated with a ;
Its much faster than before but now i get this error : "commands out of sync you cant run this command now"

Comment: @user3639702 - I say no to Partitioning.  And No to trying to issue multiple statements at once.

Answer (score 1):

Database technology loves to scale by rows.

- One connection for the entire task.
- For each table, construct a single `INSERT` with up to 1000 in it.  Repeat until all the desired rows are inserted in that table.
- `Use autocommit=ON` if you usually can do batch es of 1000.
- If you are forced to do only one row per table, then use `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` around each 1000 (or so) rows (inserted across multiple tables).
- It is *usually* better to have a billion rows in a single table.  Sometimes Partitioning is better.  10K different tables with identical schemas is almost always the worst approach.  Please provide your argument in favor of such so I can poke holes in it.
- Please provide the Selects (or whatever) that will be hitting this big dataset.  This will help me advise on Partitioning and/or Sharding.
- Yes, a `COMMIT` of 100M rows at once would be "overwhelming", though it would work.  The "1000" I suggest above is a reasonable compromise between many factors that come into play.  It is very close to optimal in all situations.
- `select all the lines that values=something` will be fast if you have `INDEX(values)`.
- Do not try to execute multiple queries in a single call.

(Based on Comments)

If `20734707098720918237747770989023747098709987213447` is stored in a column declared `VARCHAR(99)` *and* that you have `INDEX(big_number)` *and* you say `... WHERE big_number LIKE '2073470709%';`, then the query should be very efficient *even without* an index on `short_int`.

But, once you have that index, there is no need to work with `short_int`; simply say `... WHERE big_number = "20734707098720918237747770989023747098709987213447"`.

If `big_number` is too large to `INDEX`, say so; there is a workaround that we can discuss.

65536 *tables* might run into OS problems (since each `TABLE` needs at least 1 *file* on disk).  Even if the OS does not complain, there are many aspects of the database and the OS that make it likely that using that many tables will be slow.

If `big_number` is hex, then its size could be cut in half by using `VARBINARY(..)` or `BLOB` instead of `VARCHAR(..)` or `TEXT`.  It will take some changes to the SQL; we can discuss the details.

It is actually slower to pick one of many tables, then `SELECT` (with an `INDEX`) from that table--than to have a single big table with a suitable `INDEX`.  (Ditto for `PARTITIONing`.)

The limit on table size is 32TB.  If you are threatening to hit that, we can work around it.

`INSERT ... 1098234407980983709870987123770928137409128347` -- since that "number" is being put into a `VARCHAR`, it should be quoted.  (It seems to work without quotes, but I worry.)

Run this.  (It will take a long time if the table is huge.)

```
ALTER TABLE t_name
    ADD INDEX(int_short),
    ADD INDEX(int_long);
```

The index on int_short will help your query; the other index will help my suggestion (which eliminates the need for int_short).

(I that sample does not look like hex.  That, and a max of 80, eliminate the need to discuss my comments about `TEXT` and `BLOB`.)

**More**

It seems there is not enough disk space to add the desired index to the table.

Plan A:  bigger disk -- at least 800GB.

Plan B:  `DECIMAL` compression.  Your `1098234407980983709870987123770928137409128347` is 47 digits, but the `VARCHAR` asks for a max of 80.  If the column is really all digits and never longer then 64 digits, then make it `DECIMAL(64,0)` (or less if safe to do so).  That would occupy 29 bytes (or less if you can go less than "64").  This is compared to 47 (or more?) for `VARCHAR`.

Plan C:  If it is not all digits or not limited to 64, please specify the type and max size of the data.  I have some other thoughts that may work for compression.

In any case, get rid of `r_short` and the index on it.  Simply work with `r`.  (This saves the space take for that column and its index, plus it simplifies your code.)

While we are at it, would you care to discuss what `trx_id` looks like.  It may benefit from a similar shrinkage.

And...  The table currently has about 1.6 billion rows?  The `PRIMARY KEY` is (`INT SIGNED`) will top out at about 2.0 billion.  You should probably fix that at the same time.  `INT UNSIGNED` tops out at 4 billion and takes the same 4 bytes of space.  If that is not safe in the long run, let's discuss it further.  Do you use `id` for joining to some other table?  Is there some column (or combination of columns) that is unique -- hence could be used *in place of* `id` for the PK?

Comment: this is the database details.
Single database would be arround 200 go.
1 000 000 000 rows.
4 columns.
1s is id increment, (I don t use this one in my query)
2nd is a big number (I record it as a string in the db because I got problem recording)
- 3rd is just the 2nd column bit number first few digit.
I take the first 8 digits of the big number and record it as a int.
For exemple if my 2nd column big number is 1203840812083880808012808038080123, the short version would be 12038408.

Comment: The last column is just a random id, I dont use that in my search querry.
The data base will be hit 10k times / sec with this command.
select * from table_name where short_int = 47203947

Comment: My goal is to find number that are perfectly the same as the big number column. But sinces its very slow to work with the big number column, I first select "candidate" with the short_int column, then I see compare all the result to see if I got a perfect match.
So for example if I am searching this number in the db 20734707098720918237747770989023747098709987213447. I will first look in the short_int column all the number that fits  2073470709.
Then I will compare the results in python to see if i got perfect match with my input.

Comment: I tried this kind of querry in a single db but its kind of slow. So I decided to make some test with many smaller db instead of a big single one.
The name of the dbs is just the big number of each rows hex value.

Comment: I found that using hex values instead of plain number got me a better distribution of the data.
Basiqueley I got 16x16x16x16 = 65536 tables

Comment: Using hex instead of raw number for tables names has another good side.
If I use number columns, as my table will grow and get bigger and bigger, I would have thousands of big number that  will have the same short_int, but by using hex for the column name, I dispatch all those data in different tables. So it is working as a pre-filter for my querry.

Comment: I have done BTree indexing on all the tables for the short_int column.

Comment: @user3639702 - What indexes?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for that query that is too slow.  We really need to check the datatypes, indexes and the formulation of the query.

Comment: @user3639702 - and I addressed most of your Comments via additions to my Answer.

Comment: Sorry but I dont realy understand what you mean by "SHOW CREATE TABLE" and "EXPLAIN SELECT" but this is the command I use to create the tables. 
CREATE TABLE t_name (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, int_short INT, int_long VARCHAR(80))

Comment: This is the command I use to insert data :
INSERT INTO t_name (int_short, int_long) VALUES ( 10982344, 1098234407980983709870987123770928137409128347)

Comment: @user3639702 - I added more to my Answer.

Comment: Ok, I just saw your answer, I am very new to database so I will read all your comment carrefully to see what I am doing wrong. Thank for your help, I appreciate.

Comment: I just made the db as you said, now I got one big 400 gb database.  I tried the indexing with ALTER TABLE t_name ADD INDEX(col_name) on both, int_short and int_long, but I failled to create them with a database error. I just could create a btree index on short_int colomn with CREATE INDEX short_int_index on t_name (short_int) USING BTREE. But now I run in a problem, my insert are getting verry slow and I can only perform 5000 search per minute on average. I would like to go much faster for the search at least.

Comment: @user3639702 - How much RAM?  SSD or HDD?  And let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` no that the index(es) have been added.  Plus a typical search query.  (With HDD and a table much bigger than RAM, random fetches will have to hit the disk about once per query, thereby limiting to about 100 queries per second.)

Comment: I run it on my computer, its 16go ram, the harddrive is ssd nvme (samsung evo 970)

Comment: this is the output of the SHOW CREATE TABLE

Comment: ('r', 'CREATE TABLE `r` (\n  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `r_short` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  `r` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `trx_id` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),\n  KEY `r_short` (`r_short`),\n  KEY `r_short_index` (`r_short`) USING BTREE\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1651988598 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci')

Comment: @user3639702 - You have 2 indexes on `r_short` and no index on `r`.

Comment: I dont know why but, I ran into an error twice, but when I tried to make the index again it said I already had one. Mabe it succeded. Should I get rid of one of them?

Comment: The r index didn't succeded at all, I could not make it. Mabe because the strings are to big.

Comment: @user3639702 - "Didn't succeed" -- Was there any error message?  Did you run out of disk space?  I see nothing to prevent `INDEX(r)`.  `ALTER TABLE r DROP INDEX "r_short_index";`  `ALTER TABLE r ADD INDEX (r)`;

Comment: yes, I dont remember the error but it was something related with the disk error. I will try to make and index in the r column again to see what error it is exactly.

Comment: Check disk space while you are at it.  And `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'r';`

Comment: ('r', 'InnoDB', 10, 'Dynamic', 1632540619, 185, 303647686656, 0, 0, 37410045952, 1651988598, datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 23, 18, 17, 35), datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 23, 11, 23, 16), None, 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci', None, '', '')
this is the SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'r'

Comment: I deleted the index like u said with ALTER TABLE r DROP INDEX "r_short_index"

Comment: 303GB of data, 37GB of index(es).  `INDEX(r)` may take another 100GB.  I hope your disk is at least 800GB.  Although some `ALTERs` can be done without copying the table over, some require a `COPY`.  Hence the 2x recommendation on disk size.

Comment: I tried the index on r again, I got the same error : (HY000) temporary file write failure

Comment: I got 86 go left in my ddr

Comment: @user3639702 - I added more.